# Show that if $(a,n)=d>1$ and $k$ is any positive integer, then $a^k\not\equiv 1\pmod{n}.$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

So I know that if $(a,n)=1$, then $a^{\phi(n)}≡1\pmod{n}$ by Euler's Theorem. I also know that $d \mid a^k$ and obviously $d \mid n$. I know I probably need to use this in the proof, but I just don't know how to get started.

Comment: $a\equiv b \pmod n$ means $a = b + nk$

Answer (score 2):

Given $(a,n) = d > 1$, suppose for the sake of contradiction that for some $k > 0$, $a^k \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$. Rewrite the equivalence as $(a/d)^kd^k \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$. This implies that $d^k$ is the multiplicative inverse of $(a/d)^k$ modulo $n$. Such an inverse exists if and only if $d^k$ is relatively prime to $n$; however, since $d \mid n$, we know $d^k$ and $n$ share a factor of $d > 1$. Therefore, $d^k$ is not relatively prime to $n$, so we have a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a^k \equiv 1\bmod{n}$. Write $a=da',n=dn'$.

Then $n' \equiv n' a^k = n' a a^{k-1} =n'da' a^{k-1} = na' a^{k-1} \equiv 0 \bmod n$.

This contradicts $0< n' < n$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\gcd(a,n) = d > 1$ then $d \mid a^k, \forall k\in \mathbb{Z^+}$ and $d \mid n$.

Now let $a^k=(d\cdot x)^k$ and $n=d\cdot y$ then:

$$(d\cdot x)^k \equiv b \pmod {d\cdot y} \Rightarrow (d\cdot x)^k = d\cdot y\cdot q + b$$

$$(d\cdot x)^k - d\cdot y\cdot q = b \Rightarrow b \mid d(d^{k-1}x^k-y\cdot q)$$

Thus $gcd(d,b)=d$ and since we said $d>1 \cdots$